# Gimp transparency isn't working, even when I export with png

Tags: gimp, transparency, background

I followed videos step by step to create my image in gimp, making the background transparent. I then exported my file as a .png file. Everything looks like it worked well, until I add the image into imvu - then it appears with a black or white background. I updated my version of Gimp to 2.10.24 but it still doesn't work. Help, please?

Comment: No experience with the software, but the black or white background is often a result of saving a PNG8 file when a PNG32 file is necessary, or vice versa.

Comment: What is IMVU? Please share the PNG image here. We can tell you if it's transparent or not. If it is, then the problem is with IMVU. Note that social media sites often convert PNG images automatically to JPEG when uploading. JPEG doesn't support transparency.

Comment: Thanks for the comments :) I'm pretty sure now the problem is with imvu and not with Gimp.

Comment: @BillyKerr Indeed. The first thing to do in such case is to re-downlad the image from the site and compare ti with the one thatt you uploaded.